# SQL SELECT SUM all the rows for total

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I ran a `SELECT` statement to query these results. I would like to know how to `SUM` the total of the "Quantity Sold". How is that done?

Results:

[image: Results]

Currently, this is the query:

```
SELECT
     "CustomerName",
     "Completed Date",
     "System Size" AS 'Quantity Sold',
     (NOW() -INTERVAL 26 DAY) AS 'Pay Period Start Date',
     (NOW() -INTERVAL 13 DAY) AS 'Pay Period End Date',
     (SELECT SUM("System Size") FROM  Deals) AS 'System Size Installed'
FROM  Deals
```

I then have a second Excel report and need to manually input a "Total Cost" during a said pay period. Any ideas on how to automate this step?

Comment: You put `mysql sum` in to google and follow the links and tutorials.

Comment: If you add sum(`quantity sold`) to your query, this doesn't show expected result?

Comment: I do get a result, however, I feel it is adding the total of the full table and not my query. The total for the table is 5016 records and the sum for those are 10818.3699999986. My query pulls only 30 records but gives me that same sum. (10818.3699999986) I should get 230.00. I know this because I pulled the report and manually summed the 30 records.

Comment: Have you tried Google???  Try to Google `GROUP BY`

Comment: Yes, Google got me to what I posted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    "CustomerName",
    DATE("Completed Date")   AS "Completed Date",
    SUM("System Size")       AS "Quantity Sold",
    (NOW() -INTERVAL 26 DAY) AS "Pay Period Start Date",
    (NOW() -INTERVAL 13 DAY) AS "Pay Period End Date",
    (SELECT SUM("System Size") FROM  Deals) AS "System Size Installed"
FROM
    Deals
GROUP BY
    "CustomerName",
    DATE("Completed Date")
ORDER BY
    "CustomerName",
    DATE("Completed Date")
```

Using `DATE()` is only "just in case" your column also include a time part to the value, but does assume it's NOT a string column.

Also, I strongly recommend against using spaces in column names.  You wouldn't use spaces in variable names, so don't use them in SQL column names...

Comment: I think you should add SUM("Quantity Sold") too.

Comment: I would like to change the names but not possible at this point and do I have the time, but I agree. Thanks, I will run this.

Comment: @FatemehNB - Line 4 = `SUM("System Size")       AS "Quantity Sold",`